# NX Enforce Scoped Imports and Disallow Imports from rootDir

Tags: eslint, tsconfig, nrwl-nx

Is there a way with NX, TS config or ESLint that we can error on imports from our NX apps and libs folders, or the rootDir in general and enforce using the scoped package names?

Some developers in our org are importing, committing, PR and merging imports like below. I think some of it is from IDE doing auto imports in cases where a class doesn't have an exported path.

We are using scoped paths in tsconfig.base.json, to try and force using the scopes. Especially since, we'll have versioning concerns soon between the libraries and apps and will start publishing versions.

```
// seeing this
import * from 'libs/lib-xyz/src/foo/bar';

// we want
import * from '@us/lib-xyx';
```

I'm thinking a husky pre-commit hook, but thinking there is a more elegant way to solve with TS config or ES Lint, but everything I've tried completely ignores the directories or something else unwanted.